# Ошибка Suspend functions cannot be made Composable при попытке скачать файл

Tags: android, kotlin, coroutine, android-jetpack-compose

При попытке скачать файл, получаю ошибку:

> Suspend functions cannot be made Composable

Как можно поправить?

```
@Composable
suspend fun CheckVerMain(): File? {

val context = LocalContext.current
    val retrofit = RetrofitProvider.getInstance().create(CheckVerService::class.java)

    return try {
        val requestBody = retrofit.downloadFile()
        val file = requestBody.byteStream().toContent(context)

        file
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.d("res", "ERROR DOWNLOAD = ${e.printStackTrace()}")
        null
    }
}

private fun InputStream.toContent(context: Context): File {

    use {
        val file = File(context.cacheDir, "book.epub")

        FileOutputStream(file).use { output ->
            val buffer = ByteArray(4 * 1024)
            var read: Int
            while (read(buffer).also { read = it } != -1) {
                output.write(buffer, 0, read)
            }
            output.flush()
        }
        return file
    }
}
```

Comment: Текст ошибки вполне информативен. Либо `@Composable` уберите, либо `suspend`.

Comment: А если надо и то и то? Куда рыть?

Comment: Короткий ответ на ваш вопрос -- убрать аннотацию `@Composable` и передать `cacheDir` аргументом, получение контекста в этой функции выглядит ненужным. Если это вам не подходит, покажите код, где у вас используется функция `CheckVerMain()`. Без этой информации ваш вопрос не совсем понятен.

Comment: Кода пока нет. Но функция планируется использоваться при чтении json файла,  который необходимо скачать..

Comment: Так как вы еще не решили, как именно вы будете использовать эту функцию, то скорей всего вам сначала поднадобится [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1517144).

Answer (score 0):

Общение Composable-функции с внешим миром это [side-эффект](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects).

Вызывать suspend-функцию из Composable-функции конечно же нельзя. Рекомпозиция (вызов Composable-функции) может происходить ~100 раз в секунду, столько раз была бы вызвана функция `downloadFile()`, если бы код удалось скомпилировать.

Чтобы подружить suspend и Composable, нужно сформировать [состояние (стейт)](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state). Создать Compose-стейт на основе suspend-функции можно с помощью [`produceState`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects#producestate):

```kotlin
@Composable
fun FileContent() {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val retrofit = (context as App).retrofit
    val file by produceState(initialValue = null as File?) {
        value = retrofit.downloadFile()
    }
    Text("Файл: ${file?.name}")
}
```

1. Получение файла занимает время, сначала на экран будет выведено `Файл: null`. Как только файл будет получен, текст автоматически обновится.
2. Не создавайте `retrofit` в контексте Composable-функции, так как объект будет создаваться каждый раз при [рекомпозиции](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/mental-model#recomposition) Composable-функции и это может повлиять на производительность. Создайте объект `retrofit` один раз в контексте Application и далее пользуйтесь этим объектом.
3. Не забудьте добавить следующий импорт, чтобы заработала конструкция [`by`](https://kotlinlang.ru/docs/delegated-properties.html):

   ```kotlin
   import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
   ```
4. Посмотрите [в документации](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects) какие еще бывают side-эффекты в мире Compose.

Answer (score 0):

Исходя из приведенного кода, вам не нужен контекст, а нужна лишь директория `cacheDir`.

Поэтому, чтобы исправить эту ошибку, уберите аннотацию `@Composable` и передайте в функцию `cacheDir`.

В таком случае функцию следует назвать с маленькой буквы и желательно придумать более осмысленное название для функции:

```kotlin
suspend fun downloadBookOrNull(cacheDir: File): File? {
    ...
}
```

Когда вы определитесь, как именно будет использоваться эта функция в вашем коде, то вам поднадобится [другой ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1517083).